# Сryptanalysis of Hill's method

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher, algebraic-attack

The brutal ciphertext is given. The text volume is more than 6000 characters. It is known that the text is encrypted with a 7x7 matrix. Unknown key and plaintext. Is it possible to crack this code? Russian alphabet. The vector is recalculated modulo 32 (not 26).

1. The search of all matrices on a computer is not possible! It will take some years :)
2. There was an idea to divide the text into groups of 7 characters. Next, compare the same tokens in the same positions…

   - Total it turned out 3 groups with the same substring.
   - There were 2 substrings of length 4.
   - Several pairs of substrings of length 3.
   - Some of them occur 3 times.

Can this somehow help solve the system to find the key or the source code?

Comment: can you express more about the key (matrix). what is the range for the indices?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "The cryptanalysis of a Hill cipher".  The ciphertext is not given.  If you can pose specific questions about breaking a Hill cipher, you will surely receive a response.

Comment: @DisplayName  Your question is incomplete.